How can I identify the name of recitation of Qur'an in My phone
There's a particular surah in my phone but am struggling to know the reciters of the surah because I collected the surah through xender from someone and I want to download the remaining surah. How can I do it?

Here are a couple of things you can try:

Share the file on an Islamic discussion forum and ask if someone knows the reciter.

Go through the recitation of the Surah by various famous reciters and try to match it manually.

Sometimes the file might have metadata which could contain the name of the reciter. Try examining the file with software which shows you the metadata.



Try audio recognition apps like Shazam to identify the reciter.
